# Are there any rules in Star Realms for when you have no deck?

Tags: star-realms

I play the Star Realms app (against a not-super-intelligent computer) periodically.

Today, I found an interesting situation. The AI has only Machine Base in play and I am forcing him to discard ~5 cards a turn. This means that the AI is consistently drawing/trashing a card, since apparently it will *always* use a base.

This means that they will systematically deplete their deck, until they have no more cards.

While in a PVP situation it's unlikely that your opponent would do this, and I could very easily win now, it's amusing to me to consistently gain health and deplete their deck - are there any rules for Star Realms about this situation? Can you buy a scout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen in an actual game if a person trashes all of their economy in order to get more damage efficiency.  A person with no money in their deck cannot purchase anything since the cheapest card in the market costs 1 (scouts are not in the market).  This is different from Dominion, where you can buy copper for 0.

Additionally, if you have fewer than five cards in your deck at the end of a turn (either because of trashing or because your deck is mostly bases and you have all of them out), you draw as many cards as you can (namely all the cards in your deck).

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a legitimate scenario when using a card denial strategy if the AI keeps trashing a card.  Also, no, you cannot buy a scout.  They should never be on the market and are only part of a starting hand.